# What is canvas fingerprinting? How to counter it?

Tags: privacy, fingerprinting

I know about these methods and how to counter them:

- WebGL fingerprinting
- Navigator data collecting
- Flash plugin fingerprinting
- Java applets

  **My questions:**
- What about Canvas Fingerprinting? How to counter it?
- Are there any other methods of fingerprinting?
- Is disabling webGL plugin in firefox through `about:config` tab has any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas fingerprinting exploits the fact that rendered text varies and depends on the users operating system, browser, video card, video driver and installed fonts. Hidden text is rendered and the result is used to track a user with high reliability, although the fingerprint can change over time when additional fonts are installed (see also the [Wikipedia article on canvas fingderprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting))

It's hard to distinguish between legitimate use of the canvas object and malicious use thereof. The Tor-Browser for example shows a warning for every canvas object and leaves the decision to render it to the user.

Counter measures include:

- disabling JavaScript (rendering many sites unusable)
- blacklisting known external tracker sites
- adding random data to canvas elements

In the end, everything that makes your user unique can be used for fingerprinting. For example if you are the only one that disabled WebGL in Firefox, you can be tracked.

Comment: Would you recommend a software that randomize fingerprinting data?

Comment: I've found out that the best way to fight fingerprinting in general is using a chromium-based browser "Mimic", I would also recommend an openNIC DNS which support DNScrypt to avoid ISP eyes.

Comment: that depends a lot on what should be accomplished. i can't give a general recommendation, that's out of the scope of stackoverflow. privacy in general is more than one piece of software.

Comment: What about audio fingerprinting? How to counter it?

Comment: if the above post answered your original question, you should accept it. additional enquiries should be asked in a new question.

Comment: There is 3 questions, you only answered 2

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts